# How to subset from aov summary in R?

Tags: r, function, regression, subset, anova

Maybe this is a simple question but I'm wondering how can I subset `DF` and `F.values` for the terms appearing in an `aov` summary?

For example, *using the base R built-in dataset* `npk`, how can I extract the residual and other `DF`s and `F.values` that appear in the summary of the following model:

`fit <- summary(aov(yield ~ block + N * P + K, data = npk)) # example is fully reproducible`

**P.S.** I'm looking for base R solutions.

Comment: If you need the `Df`, do `fit[[1]]$Df`

Comment: Any particular reason for limiting yourself to base R? `broom::tidy` will give you a nice data frame to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fit` output is a `list` of `length` 1 (by checking `str(fit)`).  We extract it with `[[` and then do `$` or `[[` to extract the components

```
fit[[1]]$Df
#[1]  5  1  1  1  1 14 #where 14 is the Residuals df
fit[[1]]$`F value`
#[1]  4.391098 12.105541  0.537330  6.088639  1.361073        NA
```

Comment: @rnorouzian  You can use `head(fit[[1]]$'F value', -1)`

Comment: To catch the last element use `tail(v1, 1)` and to remove the first element `tail(v1, -1)`

Comment: Yes, a `NULL` instead of `NA` solved everything. thank you bro!